# how to parse a Google Maps geocoding result

Tags: php, json, google-maps, geolocation, google-maps-api-3

I want to retrieve Geo address from given latitude and longitude using geocoding,
using the given example on the site 
 http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true 
I just need city name New York in this example and country name i.e United States. But the problem is there are more than one appearances of
these words as long_name.

My question how can I parse this json/xml in php to get just city name and country.

```
$url= file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=40.714‌​224,-73.961452&sensor=true'); 
$xml = simplexml_load_string($url); 
$tracks = $xml->result; 
$temp; $city; $country; 
foreach($tracks as $key) 
{ 
    foreach($key->address_component as $val) 
    { 
        $temp= $val->long_name; 
        if($val->type=="locality") 
        { 
          $city=$temp; 
        }else if($val->type=="country") 
       { 
         $country=$temp; 
       }  
    }  
  } 
  echo $country."<br />"; echo $city;

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GeocodeResponse>
 <status>OK</status>
 <result>
  <type>street_address</type>
  <formatted_address>277 Bedford Avenue, Brooklyn, New York 11211, USA</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>277</long_name>
   <short_name>277</short_name>
   <type>street_number</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Bedford Avenue</long_name>
   <short_name>Bedford Ave</short_name>
   <type>route</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Williamsburg</long_name>
   <short_name>Williamsburg</short_name>
   <type>neighborhood</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Brooklyn</long_name>
   <short_name>Brooklyn</short_name>
   <type>sublocality</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Kings</long_name>
   <short_name>Kings</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>New York</long_name>
   <short_name>NY</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>USA</long_name>
   <short_name>US</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>11211</long_name>
   <short_name>11211</short_name>
   <type>postal_code</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>40.7142320</lat>
    <lng>-73.9612889</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>ROOFTOP</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>40.7128830</lat>
     <lng>-73.9626379</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>40.7155810</lat>
     <lng>-73.9599399</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
  </geometry>
 </result>
 <result>
  <type>bus_station</type>
  <type>transit_station</type>
  <type>establishment</type>
  <formatted_address>Grand St/Bedford Av, Brooklyn, New York 11211, USA</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Grand St/Bedford Av</long_name>
   <short_name>Grand St/Bedford Av</short_name>
   <type>bus_station</type>
   <type>transit_station</type>
   <type>establishment</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Williamsburg</long_name>
   <short_name>Williamsburg</short_name>
   <type>neighborhood</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Brooklyn</long_name>
   <short_name>Brooklyn</short_name>
   <type>sublocality</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Kings</long_name>
   <short_name>Kings</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>New York</long_name>
   <short_name>NY</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>USA</long_name>
   <short_name>US</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>11211</long_name>
   <short_name>11211</short_name>
   <type>postal_code</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>40.7143210</lat>
    <lng>-73.9611510</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>40.7129720</lat>
     <lng>-73.9625000</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>40.7156700</lat>
     <lng>-73.9598020</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
  </geometry>
 </result>
 <result>
  <type>bus_station</type>
  <type>transit_station</type>
  <type>establishment</type>
  <formatted_address>Grand St/Bedford Av, Brooklyn, New York 11249, USA</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Grand St/Bedford Av</long_name>
   <short_name>Grand St/Bedford Av</short_name>
   <type>bus_station</type>
   <type>transit_station</type>
   <type>establishment</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Williamsburg</long_name>
   <short_name>Williamsburg</short_name>
   <type>neighborhood</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Brooklyn</long_name>
   <short_name>Brooklyn</short_name>
   <type>sublocality</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Kings</long_name>
   <short_name>Kings</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>New York</long_name>
   <short_name>NY</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>USA</long_name>
   <short_name>US</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>11249</long_name>
   <short_name>11249</short_name>
   <type>postal_code</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>40.7146840</lat>
    <lng>-73.9615630</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>40.7133350</lat>
     <lng>-73.9629120</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>40.7160330</lat>
     <lng>-73.9602140</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
  </geometry>
 </result>
 <result>
  <type>bus_station</type>
  <type>transit_station</type>
  <type>establishment</type>
  <formatted_address>Bedford Av/Grand St, Brooklyn, New York 11211, USA</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Bedford Av/Grand St</long_name>
   <short_name>Bedford Av/Grand St</short_name>
   <type>bus_station</type>
   <type>transit_station</type>
   <type>establishment</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Williamsburg</long_name>
   <short_name>Williamsburg</short_name>
   <type>neighborhood</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Brooklyn</long_name>
   <short_name>Brooklyn</short_name>
   <type>sublocality</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Kings</long_name>
   <short_name>Kings</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>New York</long_name>
   <short_name>NY</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>USA</long_name>
   <short_name>US</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>11211</long_name>
   <short_name>11211</short_name>
   <type>postal_code</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>40.7147100</lat>
    <lng>-73.9609990</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>40.7133610</lat>
     <lng>-73.9623480</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>40.7160590</lat>
     <lng>-73.9596500</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
  </geometry>
 </result>
 <result>
  <type>postal_code</type>
  <formatted_address>Brooklyn, New York 11211, USA</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>11211</long_name>
   <short_name>11211</short_name>
   <type>postal_code</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Brooklyn</long_name>
   <short_name>Brooklyn</short_name>
   <type>sublocality</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>New York City</long_name>
   <short_name>New York City</short_name>
   <type>locality</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>New York</long_name>
   <short_name>NY</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>USA</long_name>
   <short_name>US</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>40.7093358</lat>
    <lng>-73.9565551</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>40.7008331</lat>
     <lng>-73.9644697</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>40.7280089</lat>
     <lng>-73.9207299</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
   <bounds>
    <southwest>
     <lat>40.7008331</lat>
     <lng>-73.9644697</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>40.7280089</lat>
     <lng>-73.9207299</lng>
    </northeast>
   </bounds>
  </geometry>
 </result>
 <result>
  <type>neighborhood</type>
  <type>political</type>
  <formatted_address>Williamsburg, Brooklyn, New York, USA</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Williamsburg</long_name>
   <short_name>Williamsburg</short_name>
   <type>neighborhood</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Brooklyn</long_name>
   <short_name>Brooklyn</short_name>
   <type>sublocality</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>New York City</long_name>
   <short_name>New York City</short_name>
   <type>locality</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Kings</long_name>
   <short_name>Kings</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>New York</long_name>
   <short_name>NY</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>USA</long_name>
   <short_name>US</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>40.7064461</lat>
    <lng>-73.9536163</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>40.6979329</lat>
     <lng>-73.9698450</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>40.7251773</lat>
     <lng>-73.9364980</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
   <bounds>
    <southwest>
     <lat>40.6979329</lat>
     <lng>-73.9698450</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>40.7251773</lat>
     <lng>-73.9364980</lng>
    </northeast>
   </bounds>
  </geometry>
 </result>
 <result>
  <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
  <type>political</type>
  <formatted_address>Kings, New York, USA</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Kings</long_name>
   <short_name>Kings</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>New York</long_name>
   <short_name>NY</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>USA</long_name>
   <short_name>US</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>40.6528762</lat>
    <lng>-73.9594940</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>40.5695637</lat>
     <lng>-74.0429503</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>40.7394460</lat>
     <lng>-73.8333651</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
   <bounds>
    <southwest>
     <lat>40.5695637</lat>
     <lng>-74.0429503</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>40.7394460</lat>
     <lng>-73.8333651</lng>
    </northeast>
   </bounds>
  </geometry>
 </result>
 <result>
  <type>sublocality</type>
  <type>political</type>
  <formatted_address>Brooklyn, New York, USA</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Brooklyn</long_name>
   <short_name>Brooklyn</short_name>
   <type>sublocality</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>New York City</long_name>
   <short_name>New York City</short_name>
   <type>locality</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Kings</long_name>
   <short_name>Kings</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>New York</long_name>
   <short_name>NY</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>USA</long_name>
   <short_name>US</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>40.6500000</lat>
    <lng>-73.9500000</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>40.5510420</lat>
     <lng>-74.0566300</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>40.7394460</lat>
     <lng>-73.8333651</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
   <bounds>
    <southwest>
     <lat>40.5510420</lat>
     <lng>-74.0566300</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>40.7394460</lat>
     <lng>-73.8333651</lng>
    </northeast>
   </bounds>
  </geometry>
 </result>
 <result>
  <type>locality</type>
  <type>political</type>
  <formatted_address>New York City, New York, USA</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>New York City</long_name>
   <short_name>New York City</short_name>
   <type>locality</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>New York</long_name>
   <short_name>NY</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>USA</long_name>
   <short_name>US</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>40.7143528</lat>
    <lng>-74.0059731</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>40.4960060</lat>
     <lng>-74.2557349</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>40.9152556</lat>
     <lng>-73.7002721</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
   <bounds>
    <southwest>
     <lat>40.4959961</lat>
     <lng>-74.2590879</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>40.9152556</lat>
     <lng>-73.7002721</lng>
    </northeast>
   </bounds>
  </geometry>
 </result>
 <result>
  <type>political</type>
  <formatted_address>USA, ニュー・ヨーク＝ノーザン・ニュー・ジャージー＝ロング・アイランド</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>ニュー・ヨーク＝ノーザン・ニュー・ジャージー＝ロング・アイランド</long_name>
   <short_name>ニュー・ヨーク＝ノーザン・ニュー・ジャージー＝ロング・アイランド</short_name>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>USA</long_name>
   <short_name>US</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>40.9590293</lat>
    <lng>-74.0300122</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>39.4985330</lat>
     <lng>-75.3585939</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>41.6018065</lat>
     <lng>-71.8562140</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
   <bounds>
    <southwest>
     <lat>39.4985330</lat>
     <lng>-75.3585939</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>41.6018065</lat>
     <lng>-71.8562140</lng>
    </northeast>
   </bounds>
  </geometry>
 </result>
 <result>
  <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
  <type>political</type>
  <formatted_address>New York, USA</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>New York</long_name>
   <short_name>NY</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>USA</long_name>
   <short_name>US</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>43.2994285</lat>
    <lng>-74.2179326</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>40.4960191</lat>
     <lng>-79.7621438</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>45.0156269</lat>
     <lng>-71.8562643</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
   <bounds>
    <southwest>
     <lat>40.4959961</lat>
     <lng>-79.7621438</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>45.0158650</lat>
     <lng>-71.8562643</lng>
    </northeast>
   </bounds>
  </geometry>
 </result>
 <result>
  <type>country</type>
  <type>political</type>
  <formatted_address>USA</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>USA</long_name>
   <short_name>US</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>37.0902400</lat>
    <lng>-95.7128910</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>25.8200000</lat>
     <lng>-124.3900000</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>49.3800000</lat>
     <lng>-66.9400000</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
   <bounds>
    <southwest>
     <lat>-90.0000000</lat>
     <lng>-180.0000000</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>90.0000000</lat>
     <lng>180.0000000</lng>
    </northeast>
   </bounds>
  </geometry>
 </result>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can check for 3 variables in the google response (json) to find the current cityname. Hence there is 3 different interpretation of the name:

```
Country
     |
AdministrativeArea
     |
     |_AdministrativeAreaName (cityname)
     |
     |_Locality_LocalityName (cityname)
     | 
     |_SubAdministrativeArea
                 |
                 |_Locality_LocalityName (cityname)



if ($this->json->Placemark[0]->AddressDetails->Country->AdministrativeArea->Locality->LocalityName != NULL) {

  $code['cityname'] = $this->json->Placemark[0]->AddressDetails->Country->AdministrativeArea->Locality->LocalityName;

} elseif ($this->json->Placemark[0]->AddressDetails->Country->AdministrativeArea->SubAdministrativeArea->Locality->LocalityName != NULL) {

  $code['cityname'] = $this->json->Placemark[0]->AddressDetails->Country->AdministrativeArea->SubAdministrativeArea->Locality->LocalityName;

}
```

If you have more then a Placemark you need to loop through all the array.

```
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "277",
               "short_name" : "277",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Bedford Avenue",
               "short_name" : "Bedford Ave",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Williamsburg",
               "short_name" : "Williamsburg",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "short_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Kings",
               "short_name" : "Kings",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "NY",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "USA",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "11211",
               "short_name" : "11211",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "277 Bedford Avenue, Brooklyn, New York 11211, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.714232,
               "lng" : -73.9612889
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7155809802915,
                  "lng" : -73.9599399197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7128830197085,
                  "lng" : -73.96263788029151
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Grand St/Bedford Av",
               "short_name" : "Grand St/Bedford Av",
               "types" : [ "bus_station", "transit_station", "establishment" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Williamsburg",
               "short_name" : "Williamsburg",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "short_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Kings",
               "short_name" : "Kings",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "NY",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "USA",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "11211",
               "short_name" : "11211",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Grand St/Bedford Av, Brooklyn, New York 11211, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.714321,
               "lng" : -73.961151
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.71566998029149,
                  "lng" : -73.95980201970849
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7129720197085,
                  "lng" : -73.96249998029151
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "bus_station", "transit_station", "establishment" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Grand St/Bedford Av",
               "short_name" : "Grand St/Bedford Av",
               "types" : [ "bus_station", "transit_station", "establishment" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Williamsburg",
               "short_name" : "Williamsburg",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "short_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Kings",
               "short_name" : "Kings",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "NY",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "USA",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "11249",
               "short_name" : "11249",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Grand St/Bedford Av, Brooklyn, New York 11249, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.714684,
               "lng" : -73.961563
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.71603298029149,
                  "lng" : -73.9602140197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7133350197085,
                  "lng" : -73.96291198029151
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "bus_station", "transit_station", "establishment" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Bedford Av/Grand St",
               "short_name" : "Bedford Av/Grand St",
               "types" : [ "bus_station", "transit_station", "establishment" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Williamsburg",
               "short_name" : "Williamsburg",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "short_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Kings",
               "short_name" : "Kings",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "NY",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "USA",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "11211",
               "short_name" : "11211",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Bedford Av/Grand St, Brooklyn, New York 11211, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.71471,
               "lng" : -73.960999
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7160589802915,
                  "lng" : -73.95965001970849
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7133610197085,
                  "lng" : -73.9623479802915
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "bus_station", "transit_station", "establishment" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "11211",
               "short_name" : "11211",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "short_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York City",
               "short_name" : "New York City",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "NY",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "USA",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Brooklyn, New York 11211, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7280089,
                  "lng" : -73.9207299
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7008331,
                  "lng" : -73.9644697
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.7093358,
               "lng" : -73.9565551
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7280089,
                  "lng" : -73.9207299
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7008331,
                  "lng" : -73.9644697
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Williamsburg",
               "short_name" : "Williamsburg",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "short_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York City",
               "short_name" : "New York City",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Kings",
               "short_name" : "Kings",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "NY",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "USA",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Williamsburg, Brooklyn, New York, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7251773,
                  "lng" : -73.936498
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.6979329,
                  "lng" : -73.96984499999999
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.7064461,
               "lng" : -73.95361629999999
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7251773,
                  "lng" : -73.936498
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.6979329,
                  "lng" : -73.96984499999999
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Kings",
               "short_name" : "Kings",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "NY",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "USA",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Kings, New York, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.739446,
                  "lng" : -73.83336509999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.5695637,
                  "lng" : -74.0429503
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.6528762,
               "lng" : -73.95949399999999
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.739446,
                  "lng" : -73.83336509999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.5695637,
                  "lng" : -74.0429503
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "short_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York City",
               "short_name" : "New York City",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Kings",
               "short_name" : "Kings",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "NY",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "USA",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Brooklyn, New York, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.739446,
                  "lng" : -73.83336509999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.551042,
                  "lng" : -74.05663
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.65,
               "lng" : -73.95
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.739446,
                  "lng" : -73.83336509999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.551042,
                  "lng" : -74.05663
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "New York City",
               "short_name" : "New York City",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "NY",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "USA",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "New York City, New York, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.91525559999999,
                  "lng" : -73.70027209999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.4959961,
                  "lng" : -74.2590879
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.7143528,
               "lng" : -74.00597309999999
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.91525559999999,
                  "lng" : -73.70027209999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.496006,
                  "lng" : -74.25573489999999
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "ニュー・ヨーク＝ノーザン・ニュー・ジャージー＝ロング・アイランド",
               "short_name" : "ニュー・ヨーク＝ノーザン・ニュー・ジャージー＝ロング・アイランド",
               "types" : [ "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "USA",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "USA, ニュー・ヨーク＝ノーザン・ニュー・ジャージー＝ロング・アイランド",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 41.6018065,
                  "lng" : -71.85621399999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 39.49853299999999,
                  "lng" : -75.3585939
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.9590293,
               "lng" : -74.0300122
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 41.6018065,
                  "lng" : -71.85621399999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 39.49853299999999,
                  "lng" : -75.3585939
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "NY",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "USA",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "New York, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 45.015865,
                  "lng" : -71.85626429999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.4959961,
                  "lng" : -79.76214379999999
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 43.2994285,
               "lng" : -74.21793260000001
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 45.0156269,
                  "lng" : -71.85626429999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.4960191,
                  "lng" : -79.76214379999999
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "USA",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 90,
                  "lng" : 180
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -90,
                  "lng" : -180
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.09024,
               "lng" : -95.712891
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 49.38,
                  "lng" : -66.94
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 25.82,
                  "lng" : -124.39
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: thnx for your reply i have used my own simple logic to solve this and share it here for help purpose `$url=  file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true');
$xml = simplexml_load_string($url);
$tracks = $xml->result;
$temp;
$city;
$country;
foreach($tracks as $key)
{    foreach($key->address_component as $val){
    $temp= $val->long_name;
   if($val->type=="locality")
   {
       $city=$temp;
   }else if($val->type=="country")
   {
       $country=$temp;
   }
}}
echo $country."<br />";
echo $city;`

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution that works for the Google Geocode JSON results.  It is a simple for loop that returns that short and long version in a string array.  Just call the function and provide the "types" in the argument.

**string[] street_number = GetJSONValueBasedOnType(record.geocode, "street_number");**

```
    public string[] GetJSONValueBasedOnType(NewGoogleGeocode gc, string WhatYouWant)
{
    string[] returns = new string[2];
    returns[0] = string.Empty;
    returns[1] = string.Empty;
    bool isInIt;

    foreach (var v in gc.results[0].address_components)
    {
        isInIt = false;
        foreach (var t in v.types)
        {
            if (t == WhatYouWant)
            {
                isInIt = true;
            }
        }
        if (isInIt)
        {
            returns[0] = v.short_name;
            returns[1] = v.long_name;
        }
    }
    return returns;
}
```