# How to get the region/city from a geocoding object?

Tags: javascript, python, google-maps-api-3

My problem is that eg `results[0].address_components[2].short_name.toLowerCase();` in some cases returns the city and in some cases the region/state. How should I do to always get the locality (city) and which element is always the admin area (region/state)?

Thanks for any insight. The manual is here http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#JSON and the two names, if they exist, I want to retrieve for a place is the admin area (state/region) and the locality (city) where one instance is as long as `India > Gujarat > Ahmedabad > Ahmedabad > Navrangpura > Shreyas Colony > Chimanlal Girdharlal Rd

I would like a solution in python or javascript preferably python and I see that there is a PHP question about this [how to parse a Google Maps geocoding result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789298/how-to-parse-a-google-maps-geocoding-result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to look at the types array and then extract the values accordingly. Further down the page they have an explanation of the different types

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types

Even then you might still have some problem. That is because of the address structure in different countries.

Comment: OK. Thanks! I also had some luck parsing this json serverside with python. I'll see which works best: javascript and python and will follow up. A link to my geospatial mapping effort is http://www.koolbusiness.com